# Mosquitto server conf for using PFX certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, mqtt, mosquitto, pfx

I had been able to get TLS connection with mosquitto and using CA.crt, server.crt, server.key plus client.crt and client.key. I been able to sub and pub no problem using MQTTfx and just command lines. below is my full setting for anyone who needs it, and I am looking for some help to use pfx certs.

I am asked to figure out how to sub and pub to the broker using PFX client cert(contains client.crt and client.key) along with ca.crt, which I don't see as option to MQTTfx 1.7 or in CMD examples I can find online. Wondering anyone had this experience using PFX that can enlighten me with broker settings and sub examples.

**Broker setting:**

```
listener 8883
log_type error
log_type notice
log_type information
log_type debug
require_certificate true
use_identity_as_username true
cafile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\cert\ca.crt
keyfile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\cert\server.key
certfile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\cert\server.crt
```

**Subscription command line**

```
mosquitto_sub -h 192.167.41.17 -t home/garden/fountain --cafile "C:\ca.crt" --cert "C:\client.crt" --key "c:\client.key" -d -p 8883
```

**Certificates used in this project is self signed:**
**To create CA:**

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 2048

openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
```

**To create server:**

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048

openssl req -new -out server.csr -key server.key

openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 360
```

**To create client:**

```
openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048

openssl req -new -out client.csr -key client.key

openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 360
```

**To create the pfx:**

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certbag.pfx -inkey client.key -in client.crt -in
```

[image: MQTTfx settings]

Comment: And what is exactly your question? The "PFX" file is kind of a container for both a key and a certificate. If a given software can use the PFX directly you can extract the certificate and key from it and use those with the application.

Comment: The only question I would ask is what happens if you uncheck the "PEM Formatted" box?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for looking, I was asked to use client PFX file from actual client, was trying to connect just with MQTTfx, but I didn't find any option to do so where it can take ca.crt and client.pfx so I am trying to setup my own mosquitto broker to test it out, but hm...I am not sure what to set on the broker side and nor do I know what to set in SSL/TLS settings of MQTTfx, maybe you are right, in our use we should extract the key from it. Will take into consideration. Thanks!

Comment: @hardillb I tried and it will read java.security.invalidKeyException: invalid key format

Comment: The broker is already configured, there is nothing to change, like the command line tools it will only take the pem files

Comment: That makes perfect sense, and your prompt response of help has inspired me to be more involved in the stack overflow community^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mosquitto_pub` & `mosquitto_sub` will only accept PEM encoded files for all certificates/key. There is no way directly use a PKCS12 (.p12 or .pfx) certificate store/bundle with these tools.

If version v1.7 of MQTT.fx (given the latest version if v5.0) also doesn't support being passed a PKCS12 bundle then there is no magic way you can make it, your only option is to use openssl to break it up into it's parts (cert, key and ca cert) encoded in PEM format and pass those files.